# Explicitly find all pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a^{1/a}=b^{1/b}$ and $a\ne b$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Explicitly find all pairs $(a,b)$ s.t. $a^{1/a}=b^{1/b}$ and $a\ne b$.

My multivariable calculus teacher posed this question as a fun brain teaser for the end of the semester. He said it was explicitly solvable using something we had learned but that it wasn't integration. I'm completely stuck as to how to even start this problem. If you guys could give me a hint without directly giving the solution I'd appreciate it.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22230/ab-ba-when-a-is-not-equal-to-b

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The function $x^{1/x}$ is an increasing function for $x \in (0,e]$ and a decreasing function for $x \geq e$.